# Customisable calendar view for Android

Tags: android

I am designing an app which will show a calendar with various different colours on days to denote events which are happening on each day, I have had a look at the Android calendar view but this does not offer the customisability that is needed.

Are there any such views that have the capability to change the style of individual days or am I better off creating a view from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best chance is using some open-source library/project.

Although I've never used this, I think your best option is **[TimesSquare](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/01/times-square.html)**, from Square. They have produce some great android libraries so you should be able to trust them to keep up bug-free.

Some runners up from Google top results : **[Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)** which seems to be somewhat customizable and **[Android Calendar View](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-calendar-view)** which you can use as a base and modify the code to tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Calroid looks promising, it seems to support all the customisation options I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty late but there is a library called [ZCustomCalendar](https://github.com/naishadhparmar/ZCustomCalendar) that allows you to define custom views for different types of dates.